# Getting year of Postixct format

Tags: date, timestamps, r

`"Thu Apr 21 11:15:00.375 2022"` how to get the year of this expression?

Followings are tested.

1- `as.POSIXct(strptime("Thu Apr 21 11:15:00.375 2022", format='%c'),origin='1970-01-01')`

2- `as.POSIXct("Thu Apr 21 11:15:00.375 2022", format='%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y', tz = "GMT", origin="1970-01-01")`

3- `as.POSIXct(strptime("Thu Apr 21 11:15:00.375 2022", format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT"), origin="1970-01-01")`

#1 and #2 are not working.

#3 is working but gives me the current year. The output is `"2023-04-21 11:15:00 GMT"`

**Any ideas?**

Thanks

Comment: Is it `R` programming?

Comment: If yes, better suit to https://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the date output from POSIXct as "Thu Apr 21 11:15:00.375 2022", you can always pipe it to `awk` or `cut` to return only the year (or any other part you may want).

Both of these examples return only the year portion of `2022`.

```
echo "Thu Apr 21 11:15:00.375 2022" | cut -b 25-
```

or

```
echo "Thu Apr 21 11:15:00.375 2022" | awk '{ print $5 }'
```

Comment: This is helpful. I can now execute it in any language by invoking the system function.